# Cant connect to replicaset .net driver - MongoDB

Tags: .net, vb.net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, replicaset

I am using this code :

```
Dim client = New MongoClient(ConnectionStringText)
mongo = client.GetServer()
```

In vb.net, i used the 1.7 mongo driver for .net and updated to the latest to make sure its not a version issue.

When i use the replica set connection string :

```
mongodb://[myserver1]:27017,[myserver2]:27017,[myserver3]:27017/?replicaSet=myRepName
```

I get the following error:

```
Unable to connect to a member of the replica set matching the read preference Primary: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found
```

If u connect like this (just to one server) :

```
mongodb://[myserver1]:27017
```

The code works well

Also - i used python to verify that my replica set is working with the same connection string that did not work here and there it worked well

I also tried with these options :

```
/?connect=replicaset&replicaset=myRsName&readPreference=SecondaryPreferred
```

I also tried to do this using this code :

```
    Dim servers As List(Of MongoServerAddress) = New List(Of MongoServerAddress)()
    servers.Add(New MongoServerAddress(myserver1IP, 27017))
    servers.Add(New MongoServerAddress(myserver2IP, 27017))
    servers.Add(New MongoServerAddress("myserver3IP, 27017))
    Dim settingsNew = New MongoClientSettings()
    settingsNew.ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.ReplicaSet
    settingsNew.ReplicaSetName = "myRepName"
    settingsNew.ReadPreference = New ReadPreference(ReadPreferenceMode.PrimaryPreferred)
    settingsNew.Servers = servers.ToArray()

    Dim client = New MongoClient(settingsNew)
```

And got this error :

```
Unable to connect to a member of the replica set matching the read preference Primary
```

When logging into the servers (ssh) and using the rs.status() command i get the expected results and everything seems to be working well (as i mentioned with the python driver this works...)

Any ideas ?

EDIT:

I think this might be the same issue :

> https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-826

i also tried to downgrade to 1.8.3 driver and no success.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i found the problem:

The servers were running on windows azure (ubuntu 14)
and the IP addresses as defined at the rs.status() were the internal IP's,

For some reason that caused the .net driver to not work well (can't understand how come the python did work well) yet when changing the IP addresses there to the public ones it worked,

I changed it like this :

```
$conf = rs.conf()
$conf.members[0].host = "my_public_address:27017"
rs.reconfig($conf)
```

[Used this article as a guideline - MONGODB: TROUBLESHOOTING “UNABLE TO CONNECT TO A MEMBER OF THE REPLICA SET MATCHING THE READ PREFERENCE PRIMARY”](http://www.amido.com/richard-slater/mongodb-unable-to-connect-to-a-member-of-the-replica-set-matching-the-read-preference-primary/)